# Under UWP, GetRectFromCharacterIndex does not return values adjusted to the style of the control

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

When using `GetRectFromCharacterIndex` in UWP (as opposed to WPF), the result is the absolute offset from where text entry is possible, not inside the control.

For example, the following XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="noPadding" Margin="0,0,0,20" Text="aaa"/>
```

When you call `GetRectFromCharacterIndex(0)`, returns different `Rect.Left` value on UWP and WPF.

WPF: `Rect.Left == 3`
UWP: `Rect.Left == 0`

The difference becomes even more pronounced when you restyle or otherwise the appearance of the control:

```
<TextBox x:Name="withPadding" Padding="60,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,20" Text="aaa"/>
```

WPF: `Rect.Left == 63`
UWP: `Rect.Left == 0`

How do I get the actual location of the character on the control?

**Note:** I know that I can hack it by calculating the position from the TextView that's inside the TextBox. But I am trying to understand what the **supported** way of doing this is.

Comment: By testing on my side, the result is same with you. We will report this with inner channel firstly. Currently, I'm afraid you may need to calculate it by yourself to implement the feature since no other methods of `TextBox` directly has the same feature. Or you could tell more about what you get this value for, to see if there are other ways to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So given that that's not yet properly supported, here's how I worked around it (if someone finds a "supported" solution, I will unmark my answer and mark that one)

This extension method seems to do the trick:

```
    public static Rect GetRelativeRectFromCharacterIndex(this TextBox textBox, int charIndex, bool trailingEdge)
    {
        var caret = textBox.GetRectFromCharacterIndex(charIndex, trailingEdge);

        // Hack: UWP does not properly return the location compared to the control, so we need to calculate it.
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50304918/under-uwp-getrectfromcharacterindex-does-not-return-values-adjusted-to-the-styl
        var scroller = textBox.GetDescendants().OfType<ScrollContentPresenter>().FirstOrDefault();
        var transform = scroller.TransformToVisual(textBox);
        transform.TryTransform(new Point(caret.Left, caret.Top), out var topLeft);
        transform.TryTransform(new Point(caret.Right, caret.Bottom), out var bottomRight);

        caret = new Rect(topLeft, bottomRight);
        return caret;
    }
```

Then, you need GetDescendants():

```
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetDescendants(this DependencyObject container)
    {
        var stack = new Stack<DependencyObject>();
        stack.Push(container);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = stack.Pop();
            var count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(item);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(item, i);
                yield return child;
                stack.Push(child);
            }
        }
    }
```